# Is there a way to canonicalize file path of a non-existing file?

Tags: c, file, path, posix, filepath

I would like to resolve any `"."` and `".."` references in a file name of a file that is currently not existing.

So, what I would like to do is similar to `realpath(3)`, but with the exceptions that:

- The file name may refer to a non-existing file
- Symbolic links must not be resolved (mainly because the path components may be non-existing)

Is there an existing library code that I can call do to this or do I have to write new code?

So, essentially:

- `a/../b/c.txt` would become `b/c.txt`
- `a/../../b/c.txt` would become `../b/c.txt`
- `a/./b/./c.txt` would become `a/b/c.txt`

And in case anyone wonders, I'm not doing this for security purposes: I'm writing a tool that allows arbitrary shell command execution anyway, so security is a non-issue. I just need a way to have a canonical representation for paths for comparing them.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate of another question. The basic idea is just calling `realpath` on the pathname with the final component removed if it doesn't exist.

Comment: But `realpath` resolves symlinks, and I specified that symbolic links must not be resolved.

Comment: So you want pathnames that refer to the same file, but via different symlink pathways, not to canonicalize to the same thing?

Comment: That's my plan.

Comment: Then this isn't even a filesystem operation, just a string transformation that could be done even with `sed`.

Answer (score 2):

This is code I first wrote over 30 years ago.  There are two variants of the code you're after.

The code is available under the CC-by-SA 3.0 licence used by Stack Overflow — you may use it with attribution.

```
/*
@(#)File:           $RCSfile: clnpath.c,v $
@(#)Version:        $Revision: 2.19 $
@(#)Last changed:   $Date: 2017/03/26 06:32:49 $
@(#)Purpose:        Clean up pathname (lexical analysis only)
@(#)Author:         J Leffler
@(#)Copyright:      (C) JLSS 1987-2017
*/

/*TABSTOP=4*/

#include "clnpath.h"

#include "jlss.h"
#include "tokenise.h"
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_PATH_ELEMENTS   64  /* Number of levels of directory */
#define strequal(a,b)       (strcmp((a),(b)) == 0)
#define DIM(x)              (sizeof(x)/sizeof(*(x)))

#if !defined(lint)
/* Prevent over-aggressive optimizers from eliminating ID string */
extern const char jlss_id_clnpath_c[];
const char jlss_id_clnpath_c[] = "@(#)$Id: clnpath.c,v 2.19 2017/03/26 06:32:49 jleffler Exp $";
#endif /* lint */

void clnpath(char *path)
{
    char           *src;
    char           *dst;
    char            c;
    int             slash = 0;

    /* Convert multiple adjacent slashes to single slash */
    src = dst = path;
    while ((c = *dst++ = *src++) != '\0')
    {
        if (c == '/')
        {
            slash = 1;
            while (*src == '/')
                src++;
        }
    }

    if (slash == 0)
        return;

    /* Remove "./" from "./xxx" but leave "./" alone. */
    /* Remove "/." from "xxx/." but reduce "/." to "/". */
    /* Reduce "xxx/./yyy" to "xxx/yyy" */
    src = dst = (*path == '/') ? path + 1 : path;
    while (src[0] == '.' && src[1] == '/' && src[2] != '\0')
        src += 2;
    while ((c = *dst++ = *src++) != '\0')
    {
        if (c == '/' && src[0] == '.' && (src[1] == '\0' || src[1] == '/'))
        {
            src++;
            dst--;
        }
    }
    if (path[0] == '/' && path[1] == '.' &&
        (path[2] == '\0' || (path[2] == '/' && path[3] == '\0')))
        path[1] = '\0';

    /* Remove trailing slash, if any.  There is at most one! */
    /* dst is pointing one beyond terminating null */
    if ((dst -= 2) > path && *dst == '/')
        *dst++ = '\0';
}

/*
** clnpath2() is not part of the basic clnpath() function because it can
** change the meaning of a path name if there are symbolic links on the
** system.  For example, suppose /usr/tmp is a symbolic link to /var/tmp.
** If the user supplies /usr/tmp/../abcdef as the directory name, clnpath
** would transform that to /usr/abcdef, not to /var/abcdef which is what
** the kernel would interpret it as.
*/

void clnpath2(char *path)
{
    char *token[MAX_PATH_ELEMENTS];
    int   ntok;

    clnpath(path);

    /* Reduce "<name>/.." to "/" */
    if ((ntok = tokenise(path, "/", token, MAX_PATH_ELEMENTS, 0)) > 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ntok - 1; i++)
        {
            if (!strequal(token[i], "..") && strequal(token[i + 1], ".."))
            {
                if (*token[i] == '\0')
                    continue;
                while (i < ntok - 1)
                {
                    token[i] = token[i + 2];
                    i++;
                }
                ntok -= 2;
                i = -1;     /* Restart enclosing for loop */
            }
        }
    }

    /* Reassemble string */
    char *dst = path;
    if (ntok == 0)
    {
        *dst++ = '.';
        *dst = '\0';
    }
    else
    {
        if (token[0][0] == '\0')
        {
            int   i;
            for (i = 1; i < ntok && strequal(token[i], ".."); i++)
                ;
            if (i > 1)
            {
                int j;
                for (j = 1; i < ntok; i++)
                    token[j++] = token[i];
                ntok = j;
            }
        }
        if (ntok == 1 && token[0][0] == '\0')
        {
            *dst++ = '/';
            *dst = '\0';
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ntok; i++)
            {
                char *src = token[i];
                while ((*dst++ = *src++) != '\0')
                    ;
                *(dst - 1) = '/';
            }
            *(dst - 1) = '\0';
        }
    }
}

#if defined(TEST)

#include <stdio.h>

#include "phasedtest.h"

/* -- PHASE 1 TESTING -- */

/* -- Phase 1 - Testing clnpath() -- */
typedef struct p1_test_case
{
    const char *input;
    const char *output;
} p1_test_case;

/* This stress tests the cleaning, concentrating on the boundaries. */
static const p1_test_case p1_tests[] =
{
    { "/",                                  "/",            },
    { "//",                                 "/",            },
    { "///",                                "/",            },
    { "/.",                                 "/",            },
    { "/./",                                "/",            },
    { "/./.",                               "/",            },
    { "/././.profile",                      "/.profile",    },
    { "./",                                 ".",            },
    { "./.",                                ".",            },
    { "././",                               ".",            },
    { "./././.profile",                     ".profile",     },
    { "abc/.",                              "abc",          },
    { "abc/./def",                          "abc/def",      },
    { "./abc",                              "abc",          },

    { "//abcd///./abcd////",                "/abcd/abcd",                   },
    { "//abcd///././../defg///ddd//.",      "/abcd/../defg/ddd",            },
    { "/abcd/./../././defg/./././ddd",      "/abcd/../defg/ddd",            },
    { "//abcd//././../defg///ddd//.///",    "/abcd/../defg/ddd",            },

    /* Most of these are minimal interest in phase 1 */
    { "/usr/tmp/clnpath.c",                 "/usr/tmp/clnpath.c",           },
    { "/usr/tmp/",                          "/usr/tmp",                     },
    { "/bin/..",                            "/bin/..",                      },
    { "bin/..",                             "bin/..",                       },
    { "/bin/.",                             "/bin",                         },
    { "sub/directory",                      "sub/directory",                },
    { "sub/directory/file",                 "sub/directory/file",           },
    { "/part1/part2/../.././../",           "/part1/part2/../../..",        },
    { "/.././../usr//.//bin/./cc",          "/../../usr/bin/cc",            },
};

static void p1_tester(const void *data)
{
    const p1_test_case *test = (const p1_test_case *)data;
    char  buffer[256];

    strcpy(buffer, test->input);
    clnpath(buffer);
    if (strcmp(buffer, test->output) == 0)
        pt_pass("<<%s>> cleans to <<%s>>\n", test->input, buffer);
    else
    {
        pt_fail("<<%s>> - unexpected output from clnpath()\n", test->input);
        pt_info("Wanted <<%s>>\n", test->output);
        pt_info("Actual <<%s>>\n", buffer);
    }
}

/* -- PHASE 2 TESTING -- */

/* -- Phase 2 - Testing clnpath2() -- */
typedef struct p2_test_case
{
    const char *input;
    const char *output;
} p2_test_case;

static const p2_test_case p2_tests[] =
{
    { "/abcd/../defg/ddd",              "/defg/ddd"         },
    { "/bin/..",                        "/"                 },
    { "bin/..",                         "."                 },
    { "/usr/bin/..",                    "/usr"              },
    { "/usr/bin/../..",                 "/"                 },
    { "usr/bin/../..",                  "."                 },
    { "../part/of/../the/way",          "../part/the/way"   },
    { "/../part/of/../the/way",         "/part/the/way"     },
    { "part1/part2/../../part3",        "part3"             },
    { "part1/part2/../../../part3",     "../part3"          },
    { "/part1/part2/../../../part3",    "/part3"            },
    { "/part1/part2/../../../",         "/"                 },
    { "/../../usr/bin/cc",              "/usr/bin/cc"       },
    { "../../usr/bin/cc",               "../../usr/bin/cc"  },
    { "part1/./part2/../../part3",      "part3"             },
    { "./part1/part2/../../../part3",   "../part3"          },
    { "/part1/part2/.././../../part3",  "/part3"            },
    { "/part1/part2/../.././../",       "/"                 },
    { "/.././..//./usr///bin/cc/",      "/usr/bin/cc"       },
};

static void p2_tester(const void *data)
{
    const p2_test_case *test = (const p2_test_case *)data;
    char  buffer[256];

    strcpy(buffer, test->input);
    clnpath2(buffer);
    if (strcmp(buffer, test->output) == 0)
        pt_pass("<<%s>> cleans to <<%s>>\n", test->input, buffer);
    else
    {
        pt_fail("<<%s>> - unexpected output from clnpath2()\n", test->input);
        pt_info("Wanted <<%s>>\n", test->output);
        pt_info("Actual <<%s>>\n", buffer);
    }
}

/* -- Phased Test Infrastructure -- */

static pt_auto_phase phases[] =
{
    { p1_tester, PT_ARRAYINFO(p1_tests), 0, "Phase 1 - Testing clnpath()" },
    { p2_tester, PT_ARRAYINFO(p2_tests), 0, "Phase 2 - Testing clnpath2()" },
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

#if 0
    /* Interactive testing */
    printf("Enter pathname: ");
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != NULL)
    {
        buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1] = '\0';  /* Zap newline */
        printf("Unclean: <<%s>>\n", buffer);
        clnpath(buffer);
        printf("Clean 1: <<%s>>\n", buffer);
        clnpath2(buffer);
        printf("Clean 2: <<%s>>\n", buffer);
        printf("Enter pathname: ");
    }
    putchar('\n');
#endif /* 0 */

    return(pt_auto_harness(argc, argv, phases, DIM(phases)));
}

#endif /* TEST */
```

The second variant uses a function `tokenise()` that isn't included in the source above.  It can be made available if needed.

The code includes the testing examples, though it uses a library called "Phased Test" that I haven't formally released because I have some packaging issues to resolve.  It can be made available at short notice if it is deemed desirable.

Comment: Thanks! I indeed managed to write some code on my own yesterday, but I'll definitely run your test cases on my code, and post my code too if it's ready. I'm mainly interested in the test strings, not the test library; I can perfectly well printf() a failure number and abort() on failure.